# How to change TFS referencing URL in C# project?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I have developed a project locally then did place it on let's say abc.visualstudio.com then
copied the same code in a different folder and trying to sync it with xyz.visualstudio.com however, TFS keeps saying I don't have permission (which I have acess to both of them) but during connection still points to abc.visualstudio.com

Where can I change its pointing entry so that it can point to a new ULR which is xyz.visualstudio.com instead? in fact I need to know that how can i change TFS referencing URL in C# project?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is what I'm getting when I try to change the workspace. Now, one thing crossed my mind so might give you some idea ....I did this first time from a domain which is behind a proxy and now trying to do it from home. Can be result of that?

[image]

Comment: What is the exact message from TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally found a workaround for this problem and seems it is bug and we have to wait till it gets resolved. In order to make this work you have to remove all ("all") history of your IE this means passwords, data forms, cookies and ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new workspace.  You can do this within Visual Studio from a couple places, I usually bring up the Source Control Explorer window, open the Workspace drop-down, then choose the Workspaces... item which brings up the workspace configuration dialog.  From there you can point your existing workspace to the different local folder, or you can create a new workspace if desired.

Comment: Yes I have gone through that too but claims I have no permission to access that! PLEASE SEE THE EDIT SECTION IN MY QUESTION(TOP)  Thank you